# Why doesn't this lattice barchart wrapper work?

Tags: r, graphics, lattice

I am trying to make a wrapper of the lattice barchart function like this (to make use of the ggplot theme by default):

```
require(ggplot2)
require(lattice)
require(latticeExtra)
data(Titanic)
mytheme = ggplot2like()
gbarchart = function(...) {
    barchart(..., par.settings=mytheme)
}
gbarchart(Class ~ Freq | Sex + Age,
          as.data.frame(Titanic),
          groups = Survived,
          stack = TRUE,
          layout = c(4, 1),
          auto.key = list(title = "Survived", columns = 2),
          scales = list(x = "free"))
```

It gives an error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  ..3 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in
```

While if the `par.settings=mytheme` is added to `barchart` directly, it works:

```
barchart(Class ~ Freq | Sex + Age,
          as.data.frame(Titanic),
          groups = Survived,
          stack = TRUE,
          layout = c(4, 1),
          auto.key = list(title = "Survived", columns = 2),
          scales = list(x = "free"),
          par.settings=mytheme)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barchart is expecting individual arguments, not a pairlist. I would do something like this :

```
gbarchart = function(...) {
  args <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
  args$par.settings=mytheme
  do.call(barchart,args)
}
```

[image]

Comment: What are the differences between individual arguments and pairlist?

Comment: `paired.f <- function(list(x=1)) doSomeTasks` and `inv.f <- function(x=1) doSomeTasks`.

Comment: so the `...` is a paired list, and `do.call(func, ...)` uses  individual args inside the list?

Comment: yep! that's right! see `do.call(func,args,...)` where *args* 
a **list** of arguments to the function call

Comment: Is there a good book on such topics as these (sys.frame, sys.call, match.call, sys.parent, etc)? I find them confusing.

Comment: That's normal. `function calls` is not an easy subject. Personally I read [R Language Definition](http://www.r-project.org/)(manuals links) ans more precisely the `6.5 Manipulation of function calls` section. Hope this helps.

Comment: @agstudy ... is not a pairlist (aka a LISTSXP), it's a DOTSXP.

Comment: @qed There are some notes at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html and the following chapters

Comment: I'd say the real reason that the original code didn't work is that is a bug in `lattice:::barchart.formula`, which somehow ends up calling `lattice:::bwplot.formula` - that code is pretty hairy.

Comment: @hadley good catch!! To be honest, debugging this I get an error where it invokes `bwplot` ,...but lazy to investigate more and I just give the workaround solution.

Comment: @agstudy The workaround is fine, but the explanations are likely to confuse people because you're using non-standard R terminology